# How to prevent adding multiple restaurant food item in cart

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on food ordering android app where you can order food from multiple restaurants. I'm using sqlite datebase to save food item in cart and I'm facing a problem like if you have ordered food from restaurant A then you should not be able to add food items from restaurant B until you clear cart. So how can I do this?

Comment: Check what restaurant you're ordering from before adding a new item.  Even if we wanted to we can't give you code, you haven't posted any for us to alter.

Comment: I haven't written code yet. I'm like stuck here. I don't have any idea about how to code this. I'm using firebase wait I'll update answer with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As you haven't provided any code so here is one of the approach:**

One option is that whenever user clicks on `Add-to-Cart` button. You can take the `Id` of that product's restaurant and save it somewhere like in `SharedPreference` and then check on every `Add-to-Cart` button click that whether this product's restaurant `Id` matches with the already saved `Id`? if yes ! proceed with adding this product to cart otherwise clear the cart or show the error message.

**Note:** `Id` here refers to the **restaurantId** and not the **productId**

For Example:

You will set the default value to the restaurentId as `""` empty string or whatever you like and the checks will be like:

```
  if(restaurantId.equals("savedRestId") || savedRestId.equals(""){
    //add product to cart
    //save the restaurentId of the product
  } else {
   //error message
  }
```

**Description:**

if `restaurentId` equals to the `savedRestaurentId` `OR` the `savedRestaurentId` equals default value `""` then add the product in cart and save the `restaurentId` of that product else `Error`

Comment: If( restaurantid.equals("savedRestid"){ //add to database} else { //error message}

Comment: What should be the condition for the first time when user click add-to-cart button...

Comment: @PrasenWahane I have updated the answer kindly check if that can help !

Comment: i have checkd but that is not working. Please take a look at weight android app where It won't let you add food in cart if you have food from other restaurant. I want something like that

Comment: Thank you for you response. I'm really thankful that you're giving me your time.

Comment: I have done that by adding a file common where I have saved restid = ""; and called it while adding new item to cart and setting it to empty again when cart is empty i.e when order has been placed or adapter is empty

Comment: @PrasenWahane I am glad ! If that helped then kindly accept the answer and upvote :)

Comment: Yeah I have updated you.. thank you so much bro.. :)